# Detect mouseMove of X pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm trying to trigger an event when the cursor position moves X amount of pixels, say 100px. So, for every 100px the cursor moves in either X or Y direction, I trigger an event. This should continue for every 100px movement.

I've successfully detected the 'current' X and Y position of the cursor, and have set a pixel threshold, but am struggling with the maths on the rest. Can anyone help?

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e){

    // Vars
    var cursorX = e.clientX;
    var cursorY = e.clientY;
    var cursorThreshold = 100;

    ... detect every 100px movement here...

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep track of the old cursor positions. Then you can calculate the distance using the Pythagorean theorem:

```js
totalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oldCursorY - cursorY, 2) + Math.pow(oldCursorX - cursorX, 2))
```

This works in any direction.

Example:

<sub>Note: Unlike [@wayneOS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6001936/wayneos)'s approach (+1 from me) I do not keep track of the direction. 

It's a rather minimalistic implementation.</sub>

```js
var totalDistance = 0;
var oldCursorX, oldCursorY;

$(window).on("mousemove", function(e){
    var cursorThreshold = 100;
    
    if (oldCursorX) totalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oldCursorY - e.clientY, 2) + Math.pow(oldCursorX - e.clientX, 2));
    if (totalDistance >= cursorThreshold){
        console.log("Mouse moved 100px!");
        totalDistance = 0;
    }
    
    oldCursorX = e.clientX;
    oldCursorY = e.clientY;
});
```

```css
.d {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 100px 0 0;
    border-color: #e54646 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.s { display: flex; }
.p1 { margin-left: 100px; }
.p2 { margin-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">100px X</p>
<div class="s">
    <p class="p2">100px Y</p>
    <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No no. Your approach is also great. I just thought about linear movement in ether X or Y direction. But yours tracks it in every direction. Pretty sweet. You have my +1

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @NullDev. As this covers all directions, it best answers my question directly so will mark it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: @dungey_140 Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

To track mouse-movement for defined steps, you just need to save the last position and than check if the cursor has moved more than the threshold in one direction. Here is an example:

```js
// Vars
var lastCursorX     = null;
var lastCursorY     = null;
var cursorThreshold = 100;

$(window).on('mousemove', function(e){

    //set start-points
    if (lastCursorX === null)
      lastCursorX = e.clientX;
      
    if (lastCursorY === null)
      lastCursorY = e.clientY;
    
    //check for move left
    if (e.clientX <= lastCursorX - cursorThreshold) {
    
      lastCursorX = e.clientX;
      console.log (cursorThreshold + 'px moved left');
    
    }

    //check for move right
    if (e.clientX >= lastCursorX + cursorThreshold) {
    
      lastCursorX = e.clientX;
      console.log (cursorThreshold + 'px moved right');
    
    }
    
    //check for move up
    if (e.clientY <= lastCursorY - cursorThreshold) {
    
      lastCursorY = e.clientY;
      console.log (cursorThreshold + 'px moved up');
    
    }

    //check for move down
    if (e.clientY >= lastCursorY + cursorThreshold) {
    
      lastCursorY = e.clientY;
      console.log (cursorThreshold + 'px moved down');
    
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this @wayneOS, perfect! I don't technically need the directional detection but it's useful to see and will no doubt be useful in future. One question, where is the var clientX/Y set?

Comment: You're welcome. Just keep in mind that my solution wont track diagonal movement of 100px. Just horizontal and vertical. The `var clientX/Y` comes from the [Mouseevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).